# Devise sign in with JSON request not working when authentication fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Here is my SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    return render json: { success: true, path: root_path }
  end

  def failure
    return render json: { success: false, errors: ['Login information is incorrect, please try again'] }
  end
end
```

User#active_for_authentication

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && active_flag == 1 && has_active_subscription?
  end
```

Server Response:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-29 15:11:39 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ozQ00tw9rRWExCmlIyIZR07ovnTLab5w0W44cLAKwA4=", "user"=>{"email"=>"dennis+dlksjfdkfjsd@recruittalk.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('User', 'Athlete', 'Coach') AND "users"."email" = 'dennis+dlksjfdkfjsd@recruittalk.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  BEGIN
  AccountType Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "account_types".* FROM "account_types" WHERE "account_types"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
  AccountType Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "account_types".* FROM "account_types" WHERE "account_types"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 338ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-29 15:11:40 -0500
Processing by SessionsController#new as JSON
Completed 200 OK in 13ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

For some reason the request in the browser contains a user object with email and password as properties. The failure json doesn't render for whatever reason. Not sure what I am doing wrong

**EDIT**

```
#Devise    
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

CoffeeScript:

```
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', '.user_modal_form', (e, data) ->
      context = $(this)
      if data.success
        $('input[type="submit"]', context).hide()
        $('.spinner', context).show()

        if data.path?
          window.location.href = data.path
        else
          location.reload()
      else
        e.preventDefault()
        if data.errors?
          $('.error-messages', context).html(data.errors).parent().show()
        else
          $('button', context).show()
          $('.spinner', context).hide()
          $('.alert', context).show()

      false
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I wound up going with for those who may stumble upon this later down the road...

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb:
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true
config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :json]
```

SessionsController

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    return render json: { success: true, path: root_path }
  end

  def failure
    return render json: { success: false, errors: ['Login information is incorrect, please try again'] }
  end
end
```

routes

```
# I have implemented STI (Single Table Inheritance) into my app, therefore I skip sessions and passwords for the :user scope    
devise_for :users, skip: :registrations, controllers: { sessions: "sessions", passwords: "passwords" }
```

UserModel

```
  def active_for_authentication?
    super && active_flag == 1 && has_active_subscription?
  end

  def inactive_message
    "Your subscription has been canceled or has expired."
  end
```

CoffeeScript:

```
  $(document).on 'ajax:success', '.user_modal_form', (e, data) ->
      context = $(this)
      log data
      if data.success
        $('input[type="submit"]', context).hide()
        $('.spinner', context).show()

        if data.path?
          window.location.href = data.path
        else
          location.reload()
      else
        e.preventDefault()
        if data.errors?
          $('.error-messages', context).html(data.errors).parent().show()
        else
          $('button', context).show()
          $('.spinner', context).hide()
          $('.alert', context).show()

      false
    .on 'ajax:error', '.user_modal_form', (event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) ->
      json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
      $('.error-messages', $(this)).html(json.error).parent().show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your sessions controller to create a `failure` method on your controller that customizes your json response:

```
def auth_options
  super.merge(recall: "#{controller_path}#failure")
end

def failure
  render json: {error: "Login failed"}, status: :unauthorized
end
```

Apparently the default option for `recall` is `#{controller_path}#new`, which I suppose might make sense for html.  You can use respond_to in auth_options if you want to restrict this to only json requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting an object with login credentials, but Devise handles errors through it's FailureApp - make sure you override it so when the 401 is triggered warden recalls the custom action.

This is done in your devise initializer, `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Add this to the initializer and restart your server:

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = [:html, :json]
```

Comment: Adjusted my code above to match what I have in my app and am still getting the same odd issue of a User object being returned in JSON response